# How to fix sequelize 'npx sequelize-cli db:migrate' from docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, docker, next.js, docker-compose, sequelize-cli

I am facing

**Sequelize CLI [Node: 21.7.1, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.37.1]
|
| Loaded configuration file "database/config/config.json".
| Using environment "production".
| ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.3' (using password: YES)**

Setting `.env.production` and applying command
`sudo docker compose --env-file ./.env.production up --build`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  common:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    networks: 
      - common
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120
      
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    container_name: adminer-g-database
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    
  app:
    networks:
      - common
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
    container_name: g-app
    restart: always
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      db: 
        condition: service_healthy

    command: sh -c "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate && npm install && npm run build && npm start"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

Here is my `Dockerfile` for `Docker.mysql`:

```
#Create MySQL
FROM mysql

LABEL name=gel

EXPOSE 3306
```

It is nextJS app where trying to build app with running mysql container and applying sequelize migration command. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see in this setup where you set the database credentials, either in the server or the application.  Are you sure they match?

Comment: (Consider removing unnecessary lines from this Compose file to make the question shorter and clearer.  You should be able to delete all of the `container_name:` lines and `links:` and `networks:` blocks, for example, and I'm guessing you get the same result if you use `image: mysql` for the database without the custom Dockerfile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal working setup that should get you started.

```
├── config
│   └── config.json
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile.app
├── migrations
└── package.json
```

The `migrations` folder is empty for me.

`config.json` (I've set this up for a development environment but you can change to production once you have this working.)

```
{
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "mysql",
      "host": "db",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }
  }
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

`Dockerfile.app`

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate && npm start"]
```

`package.json` (The `start` script is just a place holder.)

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "echo 'Build script not defined'",
      "start": "echo 'Start here...'"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "mysql2": "^2.3.0",
      "sequelize": "^6.6.5", 
      "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    }
  }
```

[image]